# Conflict between android.support.v4 and google.android.gms.maps

Tags: android, sdk

```
Google map mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();
```

The above instruction is no more accepted by the SDK. Tells me:

An instance of type `android.support.v4.app.fragment` can not be of Type `com. google.android. gms. maps.support Map Fragmen`t

I am am using the samples and the libraries provided with SDK for eclipse. The same problem when I use AIDE
Thank you for any idea!

Comment: Did u try adding SupportFragment in your xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try like that ..

you need to define fragment for map in your xml file like this ..

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

If you simply test that then you will be able to see map on your device. Make sure you need to define certain permissions in your manifest file.

You can do more like this in your java class..

```
    // Map work goes over here ...
// Here you myMap is GoogleMap
           myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        //myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startLatLng));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(2));
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

That's it. You are good to go with this.

Comment: Thank you. Yes all things are  ok now.

Comment: Thank you. It 's 0K!  Merci

Answer (score 0):

AIDE needs additional linking. That's how you can compile Android Google maps project in AIDE:

1. Ensure, your project is beng compiled well using PC, for example in Eclipse.
2. For AIDE just copy google-play-services.jar from [Google play services library project]/libs to [your project]/libs folder.
   More information here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ide/JaEH3fBU8L8/oBAK2cpKRfcJ
3. Now your project must compile and run on phone.